# How to combine values in array by key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I have data that looks like this:

```
data = [
  [
    {"name":"cpumhz","data":[[1433856538,0],[1433856598,0]]},
    {"name":"mem","data":[[1433856538,13660],[1433856598,13660]]}
  ],
  [
    {"name":"cpumhz","data":[[1433856538,0],[1433856598,0]]},
    {"name":"mem","data":[[1433856538,13660],[1433856598,13660]]}
  ],
  [
    {"name":"cpumhz","data":[[1433856538,0],[1433856598,0]]},
    {"name":"mem","data":[[1433856538,13660],[1433856598,13660]]}
  ]
];
```

how would I use map to combine the array items so the `data` attributes are concatenated?

Like so:

```
data = [
  [
    {"name":"cpumhz","data":[[1433856538,0],[1433856598,0],[1433856538,0],[1433856598,0], [1433856538,0],[1433856598,0]]},
    {"name":"mem","data":[[1433856538,13660],[1433856598,13660], [1433856538,13660],[1433856598,13660], [1433856538,13660],[1433856598,13660]]}
  ]
];
```

I'm getting closer by doing it non-programatically like so:

```
res = []

cpudata = _.flatten([data[0][0].data, data[1][0].data, data[2][0].data])
res.push({name: 'cpumhz', data: cpudata})

memdata = _.flatten([data[0][1].data, data[1][1].data, data[2][1].data])
res.push({name: 'mem', data: memdata})
```

http://jsbin.com/bekodirili/7/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into using the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function. Underscore/lodash have equivalent functions.

Essentially you want to take `data` and *reduce* it down to 1 array with 2 values. Something like the following should work:

```
var reducedData = data.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    prev.forEach(function(value, index) {
        value.data = value.data.concat(cur[index].data);
    });

    return prev;
});
```

You go over each value in `data` and *reduce* it. You concat the previous sub-data with the current sub-data and return the new value.

Answer (score 2):

With lodash, you can do something like this:

```
_(data)
    .flatten()
    .groupBy('name')
    .reduce(function(result, item, key) {
        return result.concat([{
            name: key,
            data: _.flatten(_.pluck(item, 'data'))
        }]);
    }, []);
```

You use [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) to create an array that can then be grouped into an object, based on the `name` value using [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy). At this point, you have an object with two properties - `cpuhz` and `mem`.

Now it's easy to [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) the object into the array you want.